# Проверка на регистр Python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте. Можно ли как-нибудь проверить символ на регистр, не сравнивая его со списком всех букв алфавита в нужном регистре? Т.е. необходимо избежать подобной конструкции:

```
if symbol in ('a','b','c'...)
```

Comment: конструкцию, кстати, можно было бы заменить на `symbol in 'abc...'`

Comment: интересно как проверить символы $%& на регистр?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Методом [str.isupper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper).

Comment: о, отлично, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "a"
print(a.isupper())
```